# Java 8 network program intermittent Print not working

Tags: java, java-8

We have an application that has been running on Java 6 for years with no problems.

It's a GUI that communications with a server and receives Unsolicited Messages that are to be auto printed and there is new requirement to use Java 8.

Since moving to java 8 the `PrintSystem` class ( a separate thread , total of 30 threads in the App ) looks to be hanging based on looking at the log file. The PrintSystem calls the `win32com.dll` ( its running Java 8 32bit ) to send to `LPT` and `COM` ports.

Generally things are working but there are intermittent failures and when we try and capture the logs it seems the application stops logging (`java.util.logging`) at the most critical time.

We have added debug information on one of the workstations and are having trouble isolating the problem since 90% of the time everything works well.

The only thing we have been able to see in the logs is a send to the `PrintSystem` class thread and no response. And any time this has happened since the log stops logging the critical information.

Update : After doing some reading :

It seems that logging may removed by the GC if there isn't a strong enough reference. Is it possible that Java 8 has a more agressive GC and the Logger is being removed ? Also the code was recompiled for Java 8 but is there a difference in the way it runs vs being complied for Java 6 ( and running with the Java 8 JVM ) ?

And the PrintSystem Class isn't held by any other Class the way it is referenced is PrintSystem.getInstance().printMessage(message) so it is possible that Java 8 is GC'ing that class ?

Any suggestions appreciated thanks.

Comment: just check compatibility of java with server: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/sysreq.xml, https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html

Comment: Added paragraphs to make the question more readable.

Comment: The workstations are new there should be no problem with Java 8 compatibility and thanks to Phil Cooper for adding the paragraphs.

Comment: I have been doing some reading and it only makes sense but Java 8 uses more memory for the Heap that Java 6 it could be that the application is running out of room based on an Out of Memory Error ?